# Sitecore website as a subsite of an existing non-Sitecore website

Tags: configuration, site-configuration, iis

We have two websites:

1. the first one is non-Sitecore website (e.g. 'www.non-sitecore-site.com')
2. the second one is Sitecore website (e.g. 'www.sitecore-site.com')

My task is to make the second one (Sitecore-based website) as a subsite of the first website, which is accessible by 'www.non-sitecore-site.com/sitecore-site'

I tried to make a virtual forlder in IIS, convert it to a web application and set it up for Sitecore-based site folder. However it does not work, even if I configure virtualFolder and physicalFolder both equal to '/sitecore-site' in Sitecore config files.

Is it actually feasible? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Easiest way may be to use Azure WAF to [direct traffic based on the request URL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/url-route-overview) or use some sort of [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

Comment: What exactly does not work? What happens when you access /sitecore-site?

Comment: @Jeroen the site is not found when I navigate to /sitecore-site